# RStudio: using different package versions for each .Rproj

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a few older R projects I'm working with, which are dependent on several currently deprecated (or heavily modified) packages. In order for everything to work smoothly I use older versions of those packages, which I have saved in another folder and load up *manually* to `%userprofile%\documents\R\win-library\3.3` when necessary. However, this is not convenient, especially if I want to run multiple projects simultaneously, some of which requires the new and updated versions of the packages.

My question - is there a way to specify custom directories for each `.Rproj` from which it would take and load the libraries?

Comment: have you looked at the `packrat` package ... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this *much simpler*:

1. Have a top-level directory for each project, call `projA`, `projB`, ...
2. Within each of these, create a directory `libs/`, say.
3. And within each of these directories have a file `.Rprofile` with a single assignment such as `.libPaths("./libs")`

Now when you start R in the *different* project directories, each will a *separate* library directory preceding the path, allowing you to place per-projects overrides there.

In an nutshell, the approach outlines here allows you to keep the *local* and *modified* packages around as you please.  (You can even assign common directories via `.libPaths()` if you so choose.)

The nice things is that this will

1. work with any R invocation, batch or GUI or RStudio or shiny or ...
2. does not depend on any other tools, and hence
3. does not rely on RStudio or `.Rprof` files -- though you are free to use RStudio as well.

As so often, Base R is there for you.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `checkpoint` package by Revolution Analytics.

You can indicate for each main R file in a project the date for which you which you wish to load a set of packages. You can read a bit more about it [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/updated-checkpoint-package-faster-reproducibility-with-more-feedback/).

[image]

To pull snapshotted packages from a given date from the mirror use `getValidSnapshots(mranRootUrl = mranUrl())`.

To create a checkpoint:

```
# Create temporary project and set working directory

example_project <- paste0("~/checkpoint_example_project_", Sys.Date())

dir.create(example_project, recursive = TRUE)
oldwd <- setwd(example_project)


# Write dummy code file to project

cat("library(MASS)", "library(foreach)",
    sep="\n",
    file="checkpoint_example_code.R")

# Create a checkpoint by specifying a snapshot date

library(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2014-09-17")

# Check that CRAN mirror is set to MRAN snapshot
getOption("repos")

# Check that library path is set to ~/.checkpoint
.libPaths()

# Check which packages are installed in checkpoint library
installed.packages()

# cleanup
unlink(example_project, recursive = TRUE)
setwd(oldwd)
```

Comment: this is useful, but might be problematic if the OP wants to use a mixture of up-to-date and out-of-date packages ...